# RMI calls on a shared registry between two web applications throws class not found exception

Tags: java, tomcat, rmi

I have Two web applications the first do the following.
I have Two WARS
The first WAR creates and sets a remote object,

```
System.setSecurityManager(new SecurityManager());
        try {
            registry = LocateRegistry.createRegistry(Config.getRmiPort());
        } catch(RemoteException ex) {
            //if the registry is already created, try getting it instead of creating it
            registry = LocateRegistry.getRegistry(Config.getRmiPort());
        }
remotePDFGenerator remoteEasyPDFGenerator = new EasyPDFGenerator();
registryManager.rebind(PDFGeneratorRemoteInterface.REMOTE_PDF_GENERATOR_NAME, remoteEasyPDFGenerator);
```

so far so good I don't get any exceptions of any kind, and in the second war

```
ActionManager actionObj= ActionManagerImpl.getInstance();
        System.setSecurityManager(new SecurityManager());       
        try {           
            Registry registry = LocateRegistry.getRegistry(EngineConfig.getRmiPort());// same port used in WAR1
            String[] names=registry.list();//contians remotepdfGenerator (the name I set in WAR1)
            remotePDFGenerator pdfObj=registry.lookup(names[0]);//remotePDFGenerator is the remote interface in WAR1, I exported it as a jar.
            registry.unbind(names[0]);
            registry.rebind(names[0], pdfObj);// works without any problems!!!
            registry.rebind(fullRemoteName, actionObj);//trhows an exception
            ;
            String names2 []=registry.list();
        } 
        catch(AccessException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch (RemoteException e) {
            Object[] args = {fullRemoteName};
            e.printStackTrace();
            throw new RmiException(RmiException.MSG_FAILED_TO_REBIND_REMOTE_OBJECT_ARGS , args, e);
    }
```

why the second rebind throws an exception, could it be because the registry is shared between those two wars, but since the first WAR has no access to the second WAR remote interface?, even though I exported ActionManager interface as a jar and referenced it in the First WAR but still no luck.
and when I run the First war on a different machine(not a different web server), this problem doesn't occur and everything goes smooth. here is the stack trace

```
java.rmi.ServerException: RemoteException occurred in server thread; nested exception is: 
    java.rmi.UnmarshalException: error unmarshalling arguments; nested exception is: 
    java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.bla.blabla.business.cluster.actions.ActionManagerImpl_Stub (no security manager: RMI class loader disabled)
    at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.oldDispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:419)
    at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:267)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:177)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:174)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:173)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:556)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:811)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:670)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
    at sun.rmi.transport.StreamRemoteCall.exceptionReceivedFromServer(StreamRemoteCall.java:275)
    at sun.rmi.transport.StreamRemoteCall.executeCall(StreamRemoteCall.java:252)
    at sun.rmi.server.UnicastRef.invoke(UnicastRef.java:378)
    at sun.rmi.registry.RegistryImpl_Stub.rebind(Unknown Source)
    at com.bla.blabla.rmi.RmiManager.rebind(RmiManager.java:107)
    at com.bla.blabla.rmi.RmiServiceLocator.setService(RmiServiceLocator.java:242)
    at com.bla.blabla.rmi.RmiServiceLocator.setService(RmiServiceLocator.java:224)
    at com.bla.blabla.business.cluster.actions.ActionManagerImpl.init(ActionManagerImpl.java:60)
    ...
```

Comment: @EJP honestly no, I cant really pinpoint the problem, now I am not sure whether its a security issue, a class path issue, os issue, etc. and I am sure you do understand the problem iam facing better that I do, and a little help would be appreciated really:)

Comment: You have correctly identified that the problem is due to not having the second when-app's `ActionManager` class available in the context of the first web-app. You've also correctly identified the solution, but you just haven't implemented it correctly, or completely.